# React.js, why is setState changing all state values?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, reactjs

Why is setState() changing all state values? I have 4 inputs. The first two inputs are using the input autocomplete feature from google maps api.

when I enter text into the first input - the auto complete feature works fine. WhenI enter text into the second input, the first input is over written.

```
handleChange(name, value){
    this.setState({
        [name]: value
    });
}
```

If you need more detailed context please don't hesitate to ask or clone this repo:

https://github.com/malexanders/roadtrip_react

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
handleChange(name,value) {
  let newState = {}
  newState[name] = value
  this.setState(newState)
}
```

Comment: returns are error, unexpected token at first square bracket at line 'let newState[name] = value

Comment: changed the first let to var, and removed the second let. And it fixed the error. But the behaviour is the same as before. Can you possibly look at the behaviour by running it in your browser? I'm stumped...

Comment: second let is not needed

Comment: Removed second `let` as @gumingfeng pointed out correctly . I think it should work with 'let' also.

Comment: achieved the same behaviour using let, unfortunately this didn't solve my issue.

Comment: I could dive deeper into the issue, but you should really provide more details and focus where you think your issue lies (a link to your full app on github is too broad).

Answer (score 0):

to answer your question you should change a few things.

first of all you dont need a new object to do this. secondly you should change the way you are calling this

```
<Input id="from" className={style.mapFormInput} type='text' label='Origin' hint="Enter a Location" placeholder='' name='from' value={this.state.from} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, 'from')} icon="add_location" />
```

on this line you are already specifying a name on the input. so just use that on your set state.

```
handleChange = (event) => {
  this.state[event.target.name] = event.target.value
  this.setState(this.state)
}

// change your render on the input to be this

<Input id="from" className={style.mapFormInput} type='text' label='Origin' hint="Enter a Location" placeholder='' name='from' value={this.state.from} onChange={this.handleChange} icon="add_location" />
```

Comment: you don't need to bind this onChange??

Comment: Not in the render. I'm using the arrow syntax to bind this to the function on declaration